# Apache storm - supervisor port property defining in storm.yaml in storm 1.1.1

Tags: apache-storm

Below exception is observed for **supervisor property** in storm.yaml(apache-storm 1.1.1). It was working for storm 0.9.7. supervisor.slots.ports:

– 6700 – 6701 – 6702 – 6703

> c:\home>storm nimbus Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>       at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
>       at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
>       at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
>       at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436) at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412) at
>   clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866) at
>   clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865) at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408) at
>   clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5671) at
>   clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5397.invoke(core.clj:5711) at
>   clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5710) at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142) at
>   clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632) at
>   clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5753) at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137) at
>   clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:634) at
>   clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5843) at
>   clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408) at
>   org.apache.storm.command.config_value$loading__5340__auto____12278.invoke(config_value
>   .clj:16)
>           at org.apache.storm.command.config_value__init.load(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.storm.command.config_value__init.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>           at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
>           at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
>           at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
>           at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
>           at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
>           at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
>           at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
>           at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
>           at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
>           at org.apache.storm.command.config_value.(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field
>   SUPERVISOR_SLOTS_PORTS must be of type interface java.lang.Iterable .
>   Object: ? 6700 ? 6701 ? 6702 ? 6703 actual type: class
>   java.lang.String
>           at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidation$SimpleTypeValidator.validateField(ConfigValidation.java:90)
>           at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidation$NoDuplicateInListValidator.validateField(ConfigValidation.java:2
>   03)
>           at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidation.validateField(ConfigValidation.java:640)
>           at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidation.validateFields(ConfigValidation.java:675)
>           at org.apache.storm.validation.ConfigValidation.validateFields(ConfigValidation.java:654)
>           at org.apache.storm.config$validate_configs_with_schemas.invoke(config.clj:74)
>           at org.apache.storm.config$read_storm_config.invoke(config.clj:79)
>           at org.apache.storm.config$fn__908.invoke(config.clj:100)
>           at org.apache.storm.config__init.load(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.storm.config__init.(Unknown Source)
>           ... 35 more ( was unexpected at this time.

Answer (score 2):

In apache storm 1.1.1 below property format

supervisor.slots.ports:

[6700,6701,6702,6703]